# Why is the total output as if the 12.3 didn't have a point?

Tags: c#

So I wanted to add all the numbers in the string but the total is as if 12.3 was 123.

```
string[] values = { "12.3", "45", "ABC", "11", "DEF" };

decimal total = 0m;
string letters = "";

for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    string value = values[i];
    decimal number;

    if (decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
    { 
        total += number; 
    }
    else 
    { 
        letters += value; 
    }

}
Console.WriteLine($"Message: {letters}\nTotal: {total}");
```

Output

```
Message: ABCDEF
Total: 179
```

I tried modifying the string by changing `12.3` to `12,3` and it worked, but I still don't understand why?

Comment: because in your current culture the decimal-char is a comma, probably. You may provide the culture to `TryParse`.

Comment: what is the local culture? in many cultures, `.` is the group separator (not the decimal point), and is ignored in this context

Comment: it worked as in it showed Total: 68,3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like a culture conflict - meaning "is comma a group separator or a decimal point separator" (and the same for period)

By default `decimal.Parse` etc will use the ambient current culture; if you want to use a *specific* culture (perhaps the "invariant" culture) - *do that*:

```cs
if (decimal.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number))
```

You can also use a *specific* culture:

```cs
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("it");
if (decimal.TryParse(value, culture, out number))
```